# Size of divided string in Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm

Tags: c, multithreading, opencl, knuth-morris-pratt

```
int num = 0;
char tmp_string[32000];

if(l_length * lsize > 32000){
    if (l_length * lsize % 32000 == 0) {
        num = l_length * lsize / 32000;
    } else{
        num = l_length * lsize / 32000 + 1;
    }
    ...
    if ( (l_length * lsize) % num == 0) {
        size = l_length * lsize / num;
    } else{
        size = l_length * lsize / num + 1;
    }
} else {
    num = 1;
    size = l_length * lsize;
}

for (y = 0; y < num; y++) {
    if (size % lsize == 0) {
        tmp_size = size / lsize;
    } else {
        tmp_size = size / lsize + 1;
    }
    .....find the matched pattern code.....
}
.....find the matched pattern between divided string.....
```

This code is some part of finding matched pattern in string.(KMP algorithm)

I want to use only 32000byte string at one time.

So if the size of string is bigger than 32000, I split them and calculate the "num" which is the number of loop. (eg. when the size is 64000, I have to run the function twice to search the whole string)

lsize is the thread number(using the openCL actually) and l_length is the size of divided string that each thread will search.

Problem is some string must be not searched because the size is missed during the dividing function. (eg. size = l_length*lsize/num && tmp_size = size/lsize)

I tried to change the code but couldn't find the appropriate length of each thread. (Another code for finding the pattern between divided string already exist.)

How can I solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of divided string in KMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157020/size-of-divided-string-in-kmp)

Comment: Right. Sorry for the duplicate. I deleted it!